# why should the macro __STL_FUNCTION_TMPL_PARTIAL_ORDER enclose the template function in std_pair.h

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, template-argument-deduction

Today I see the following code in stl_pair.h:

```
#ifdef __STL_FUNCTION_TMPL_PARTIAL_ORDER

template <class _T1, class _T2>
inline bool operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y) {
  return !(__x == __y);
}

template <class _T1, class _T2>
inline bool operator>(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y) {
  return __y < __x;
}

#endif /* __STL_FUNCTION_TMPL_PARTIAL_ORDER */
```

i don't think the template functions have any association with the partial specialization
of function templates.
am i wrong ?

Comment: Partial ordering has nothing to do with partial specialization (which can't be done with function templates anyways). Partial ordering is about how to sort overloaded functions where multiple ones fit for a single set of arguments.

Comment: thank you for answering my question! you are right about the explanation about the partial ordering.But with google , i found that partial ordering is used in template function overloading.

Comment: Right, I should've said "to sort overloaded function *templates*".

Comment: after i have seen your answers and searched some materials,i found i shoud to learn some things about namelookup, function overloading,especially with template functions,but i don't know any specitic material,can you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### How a function call is being treated by the compiler

Calling a function template in C++ goes through the Holy Trinity of **Name Lookup** (section 3.4 in the Standard), **Template Argument Deduction** (section 14.8.2) and **Overload resolution** (section 13.3).

Apart from reading these sections in the [**C++ Standard,**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) you can read about it in the excellent book [**C++ Templates: The Complete Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842), or watch the first three Core C++ videos by Stephan T. Lavavej

- [**Core C++, 1 of n**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-1-of-n)
- [**Core C++, 2 of n**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-2-of-n)
- [**Core C++, 3 of n**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n)

### A glimpse into the Standard

As you already found out yourself, the macro was originally in the SGI implementation of the STL, at a time when there was not C++ Standard yet and compiler support for function templates was very sketchy.

> // * __STL_FUNCTION_TMPL_PARTIAL_ORDER: defined if the compiler
>   supports //   partial ordering of function templates.  (a.k.a partial
>   specialization //   of function templates.)

To find out what partial ordering of function templates is used for, here's a quote (which will become much clearer if you read the book and watch the linked videos).

**14.5.6.2 Partial ordering of function templates [temp.func.order]**

> 1 **If a function template is overloaded, the use of a function template
>   specialization might be ambiguous** because template argument deduction
>   (14.8.2) may associate the function template specialization with more
>   than one function template declaration. **Partial ordering of overloaded
>   function template declarations is used** in the following contexts **to
>   select the function template to which a function template
>   specialization refers**:
>
> — during overload resolution for a call to a
>   function template specialization (13.3.3);
>
> — when the address of a
>   function template specialization is taken;
>
> — when a placement operator
>   delete that is a function template specialization is selected to match
>   a placement operator new (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4);
>
> — when a friend function
>   declaration (14.5.4), an explicit instantiation (14.7.2) or an
>   explicit specialization (14.7.3) refers to a function template
>   specialization.
>
> 2 Partial ordering selects which of two function
>   templates is more specialized than the other by transforming each
>   template in turn (see next paragraph) and performing template argument
>   deduction using the function type. **The deduction process determines
>   whether one of the templates is more specialized than the other. If
>   so, the more specialized template is the one chosen by the partial
>   ordering process**.